# Keeping my jQuery code away from the html files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and have a created several plug ins. 
Unfortunately due to my company's coding practices they want all javascript code to be extract out to js files. This for me poses two challenges:

1. Can i extract the actual $(document).ready(..) call to a js file? So far with my limited knowledge I have not figured if this at all possible. If not, I welcome any suggestions to make this cleaner and more acceptable way to include this code.
2. There are too many javascript includes for each asp.net page header since I may be using several plugins. Is there a way to reduce the potential costly server trips that I would need to make each time I need these files?

Any suggestions, corrections are greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: To minimize the number of requests, I use a handler to combine AND compress multiple Javascript files.  This is the best of both worlds.  See it live in action at http://www.vizslapup.com

Comment: I would say it's fortunate your company wants to extract the js into separate files. It means a clean separation of concerns & it can also be cached client side.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Yes you are right that it is excellent practice to do so and it is fortunate. I meant the 'unfortunate' aspect concerning my current predicament. 

Thanks

Comment: Hi Josh,

I like your idea along with the other great responses here. Could you guide to a reference or article on how do i create the solution u suggested?

Thanks

Comment: If I can find the time, I will write up a blog post this afternoon on how I did it, and link you to it.  I use ASP.NET for the server-side code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1.` Absolutely.

Just add a script reference to your html like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/yourfile.js'></script>
```

Then just start your .js file with

```
jQuery(function() {
  foo;
  ...
  bar;
});
```

or any other shortcut ways of starting the jQuery code block.

`2.` You should run your scripts through something like [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) before sending them off to the user. This will combine the files and pack them in nicely, so that they take up less space.

Answer (score 2):

Using $(document).ready () in an external javascript file is fine - it will work exactly the same :) In fact - not only will it work, but it is good practice as it helps to seperate the content (HTML) from the behaviour (Javascript).

In response to your section question - you can combine all of your plugins into a single javascript file and link to that one inside the <head>. You could also try minifying the scripts, although this is normally a bit overkill until the site goes live.

When I use jQuery, I normally use this kind of structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- html tags such as title, link, meta etc -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/plugin.js"></script>
    <!-- more plugins included if required -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- html here -->

    <!-- script is the last thing before the ending body tag (increases performance) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your_jQuery_code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the great tips you included in ur answer. I especially like the performance tip about including the script at the end of the body. 

I just want to clarify one thing. When you state that to combine all the plugins in one file does that mean to merge all the plugins code into one file instead of seperate js files (plugin1.js, plugin2.js..)? 

Many thanks

Comment: You're correct- I was talking about taking the code from plugin1.js, plugin2.js etc and putting it all into a single javascript file (I call it plugins.js) - so in my example above, I would have all of the plugins in the single file plugin.js

Answer (score 1):

I think worrying about server trips for javascript includes is premature optimization.  Do you have any evidence that these pages are loading slowly?  The browser should be caching the javascript files.

If you do have evidence that this is a problem, you could

-combine the jquery code and any plugins into one file
-write an .net content handler to do this for you (probably overkill)

Then you can add a custom js file per page to handle page specific properties.

Comment: Thanks Tim,

all your answers have given me great guidance and insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can most definitely put your `document.ready` and all other JavaScript code in an external file.

Typically I have 2 calls - one for jQuery itself, and one minified global.js file that combines and minifies all of my individual files.

Personally, I like to use [front end blender](http://github.com/front-end/front-end-blender/tree/master) for this, but there are many other options available as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark,

Will try front end blender and minify as was suggest by Artem

Answer (score 1):

there's nothing wrong w/putting the `document.ready` call in an external file. in fact, it's what i do to separate my js from my html. if you're concerned about certain functions running on certain pages, you may sift through them with a

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (path == "/yourdir/yourpage.html") {
    //do something for this page only
}
```

or you can just include certain files only on certain pages.

Comment: Thanks Jason,
Like your suggestion about the logic about the page specific code seperation

Comment: i use it :) works very well for me! a good way to quickly figure out exactly what page you're on is to do something like alert(path);